# Regex stops at first occurrence in java

Tags: java, regex

I think there is a problem with my regex because when I looked for resolve my problem, I found only question about wanted to stop at the first occurrence. Although, I want my regex to go after the first occurrence.

Here is my code:

```
String test = "\\d";
String word = "a1ap1k7";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(test);
Matcher b = p.matcher(word);

if (b.find()) {
    int start = b.start();
    String text = b.group();
    int stop = b.end();
    System.out.println(start + text + stop);
}
```

It gives me just: 1(for the start)1(for the text)2(for the end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made just a simple error in writing this. You have to keep calling `find`

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String test = "\\d";
    String word = "a1ap1k7";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(test);
    Matcher b = p.matcher(word);

    while (b.find())
    {
        int start = b.start();
        String text = b.group();
        int stop = b.end();
        System.out.println(start + text + stop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course ! It seems very stupid now… :p do you think I have to delete this question ?

Comment: @Freddy1492 ehh not necessarily. You wouldn't know what to look for so I imagine it's not that bad to keep it up if someone else has this problem. Don't forget to mark an answer and/or upvote

Answer (score 3):

If you change your print statement to

```
System.out.println(start +":"+ text +":"+ stop);
```

you will see that result is `1:1:2` which means that you found only match between characters indexed from `1` till `2`.

If you want to find all matches like

```
1:1:2
4:1:5
6:7:7
```

instead of `if (b.find())` which can execute only once, use loop `while (b.find())` since each `find` can move you to ***one*** (next) match.

```
while (b.find()) {// <-- change 'if' to 'while'
    int start = b.start();
    String text = b.group();
    int stop = b.end();
    System.out.println(start +":"+ text +":"+ stop);
}
```